# Add active class to link with current page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a class to all the links of the various menus on the page, in order to activate the active state when the relative page is loaded.

HTML

```
<div id = "content">
  ...
  <div class = "menu-item">
    <a href="/page1/" class="menu-link"> Page1 </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  jQuery (function ($) {
      var pgurl = window.location.href.substr (window.location.href.lastIndexOf ("/") + 1);
        $ (". menu-item> a"). each (function () {
        if ($ (this) .attr ("href") == pgurl || $ (this) .attr ("href") == '')
        $ (this) .addClass ("active");
        // $ (this) .parent ("li"). addClass ("active");
      })
  });
</script>
```

I've tried other scripts too but they don't work.

I believe the problem is related to the HREF URL.

In HTML, I pass a value like / page1 / but in WordPress, the correct permalink is / parent / page1 /.

How can I fix and improve the script?

Comment: Can you provide an example for the value of `window.location.href`

Comment: Add some debugging, eg `console.log(pgurl, $(this).attr("href"))`

Comment: You seem to have a typeerror here `$(". menu-item> a")`, should be `$(".menu-item> a")`

Comment: Your issue is with .substr/.lastIndexOf - `pgurl` will *never* include any `/` but your `a` href has 2 `/` in `/page1/`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen my bad on the edit - it was *full* of rand o m spa ces - I auto-tided it in snippet editor - I've put it back how it was incase that actually *was* the issue.

Comment: This is a problem you would not have to deal with, if you let WordPress create those menus in the first place, instead of hand-coding them yourself(?).

Comment: @CBroe WordPress is only used to generate pages and manage permalinks. Everything else is customized in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this code with your real urls.

Retrieving the last valid "word" (in `\abc\page1` is `page1` or in `\xyz\page1\` is `page1`) for both url, page and menu item url. Finally I make the comparison between the two.

One more thing that would be done, remove any hashes (`url\page#abc`) and parameters (`url\page?Param=value`)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var window_location_href = 'http://your.site.com/parent/page2/';
  window_location_href = window_location_href.endsWith('/') ? window_location_href.substr(0, window_location_href.length - 1) : window_location_href;
  var pgurl = window_location_href.substr(window_location_href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);


  $(".menu-item > a").each(function() {
    var thisPage = $(this).attr("href");
    thisPage = thisPage.endsWith('/') ? thisPage.substr(0, thisPage.length - 1) : thisPage;
    thisPage = thisPage.substr(thisPage.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if (thisPage == pgurl)
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.menu-link {
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  ...
  <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="/complexPath/parent/page1/" class="menu-link"> Page1 </a>
    <a href="/complexPath/parent/page2/" class="menu-link"> Page2 </a>
    <a href="/complexPath/parent/page3/" class="menu-link"> Page3 </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To be more clear, the real end code will be this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var window_location_href = window.location.href;
  window_location_href = window_location_href.endsWith('/') ? window_location_href.substr(0, window_location_href.length - 1) : window_location_href;
  var pgurl = window_location_href.substr(window_location_href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);


  $(".menu-item > a").each(function() {
    var thisPage = $(this).attr("href");
    thisPage = thisPage.endsWith('/') ? thisPage.substr(0, thisPage.length - 1) : thisPage;
    thisPage = thisPage.substr(thisPage.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if (thisPage == pgurl)
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I not uderstand:
/* 
    ONLY FOR TEST
      On your code remove the next line and 
      replace "window_location_href" with "window.location.href"
  */

Comment: @redblade I used a variable `var window_location_href` for simulate your object `window.location.href`. In real world `window.location.href` give you the url of the current page, in my test I used a variable.

Comment: @redblade In any case if the answer of Farzad is correct (I don't know the specifics of wordpress to confirm it), it is much cleaner. Try that first.

Comment: Perfect.
Many thanks and sorry for my little know about this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){  var cururl = window.location.href;                
  const urlarray = cururl.split("/");
var last = urlarray[urlarray.length-2]);
      
        $(".menu-item> a").each(function() {
       var pageurl = $(this).attr("href"); if(pageurl.indexOf(last) > -1){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        // $ (this).parent ("li").addClass ("active"); }
      })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This script works. Now the ACTIVE class is passed correctly.
However, there is still a problem.

As I said:
Link 1 has href "page1" and slug / parent / page1 /.
Link2 has href "page" and slug / parent / page1 / page2 /

With your script, now, if I click on link 2, the active class is also passed to link 1.

Comment: This will give you the last segment of current URL. Then you can use it in the if condition:                                                               const last = pageurl.split("/");
console.log(last[last.length-2]);

Answer (score 0):

According to Wordpress Code reference page: [wp_nav_menu()#menu-item-css-classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#current-page-menu-items), the class below is added to menu items that correspond to the currently rendered page.

- `.current-menu-item`

So, basically what you can do is to just add the corresponding css for the class names which are automatically generated by wordpress:

```
.current-menu-item {
    color: red; // change the color of the current active page to #red;
}
.current-menu-parent {
    // current active menu's parent styles
}
```

You don't need to use jQuery.